# How to fetch records from one form and autofill on another form

Tags: fetch, zoho-deluge, deluge

I have an Invoicing form and a Suppliers form. I want to fetch the Address in the Suppliers form when I select the Supplier in the Invoicing form(lookup looking at the supplier in the Suppliers form, variable = Supplier).
This is the deluge code that I have so far but I keep getting errors with everything I try changing.

SupplierAutofill = Suppliers[ID == input.Supplier];
invoicing.Address.address_line_1 = Suppliers.Address.address_line_1;

I keep getting the error that invoicing is not defined when I want to update the address line in invoicing from the address line in suppliers. I am trying just one line at the moment to see if it works before I put in more code and then I get more errors.